# Having trouble working with filter method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I'm currently taking a JavaScript course and stuck on an exercise where i should create a function that, when applied to an array, returns a new array filtered with only the strings with less than 10 characters.

after some attempts i was certain that this would be the one, but failed.

```
function validUserNames(array) {
   return array.filter(function(el) { el.length < 10 } );
}
```

Anyone can help with it?

Comment: My mistake, already edited.

Comment: Probably just need to add a return statement i.e. `return el.length < 10; }`.

Comment: i already have a return statement before the filter method. are you saying i should write it in the filter method itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works ok.

```
function validUserNames(array) {
   return array.filter(function(el) { return el.length < 10 } );
}

console.log(validUserNames(['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foobarbazzz']));
```

Just add a return inside the filter function. Without it returns `undefined`. `filter` requires you to provide it with a predicate function, which is a function that **returns** true or false. When it returns true it is included in the result, when it returns false it is not included. `undefined` seems to cause it to not be included.

You can use more concise syntax which avoids the need for the return by using an arrow function, without curly braces.

i.e.

```
return array.filter(el => el.length < 10);
```

When you add back the curly braces (say your function spans multiple lines) the return statement needs to included.

i.e.

```
return array.filter(el => { return el.length < 10 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) expects a function that returns a truthy or falsy value. You currently don't return anything from the provided function, meaning that the return value is always `undefined` (falsy). Which will result in an empty array after filtering.

You should add a `return` statement within the provided function passed to `filter`:

```js
function validUserNames(array) {
  return array.filter(function(el) { return el.length < 10 } );
}
```

Or use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) without brackets (`{` and `}`) to implicitly return:

```js
function validUserNames(array) {
  return array.filter(el => el.length < 10);
}
```

Comment: That solved it! Thank you, i was a bit confused with doubling return statements and didn't realize the filter method needed the funciton to return something